# Get average string value from entire table

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how to get the average string (numbers to be treated as strings as well) value from a table and insert each string value into a row.

For example:

```
Day    Hours Break
Monday  6     1
Monday  4    0.5
Monday  6     1
Tuesday 8     2
```

The returned values would be:

```
Monday
6
1
```

The values would then be updated in a pre-existing row, for example;

```
Name  Day    Hours Break
James Monday  6     1
```

I've tried changing the MySQL query below to work but it hasn't, so here's the original:

```
SELECT       `day`,
         COUNT(`day`) AS `value_occurrence` 
FROM     `worked`
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
LIMIT    1;
```

EDIT: 
As my example is bad.

```
id  name         day       hours   break 
0  mostfrequent 
1  James        Monday     6        1
2  Joe          Wednesday  6        1
3  Jack         Tuesday    8        2
4  Sam          Monday     4       0.5
```

Then the values "Monday", "6" and "1" would be inserted into mostfrequent

Comment: How do you get the values `6 1` from your sample table?

Comment: Can you elaborate the "the average string(numbers to be treated as strings as well) value" bit? I've used min, max on string till now, so "average" string is new to me.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I thought the OP might mean mode, but the value `1` still makes no sense to me.

Comment: By average string, I mean the string that occurs the most frequent. So in my example, "Monday" occured 3 times, therefore it's selected, "6" occured 2 times, which is the most out of that column, so it's selected. And finally "1" occurs 2 times as well which is the most out of the column "break", therefore, it's selected.

Comment: @James - Why only monday? Same logic?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yeah, so in my example, "Monday" occurs 3 times and "Tuesday" only occurs once, therefore, "Monday" is the most frequently occuring value, so it's selected.

Comment: @Your second example makes it way clearer. However, "squeezing" the expected result into one result row (which seems to have the goal of running an easy "Update-Statement" - is the wrong approach) - Your desired result is as simple as 3 dedicated queries, using `count(day)`, `count(hours)` or `count(break)` along with `order by` and `limit 0,1`. This will give you 3 (unrelated) results of one value each. Finally you just have to run one update, inserting all 3 values into the dedicated row.

Comment: @dognose the example above is more like what I'm trying to achieve but that's much smaller. The actual table has 32 columns and 96 rows. Could you give an example of what you are saying for a larger scale

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select day,
    (select hours from worked w where w.day = w1.day
        group by hours order by count(*) desc limit 1) as hours, 
    (select break from worked w where w.day = w1.day
        group by break order by count(*) desc limit 1) as break
from worked w1
where day = (select day from worked w
                group by day order by count(*) desc limit 1)
group by day;
```

The `where` clause select the most frequent day, then the correlated subquery select the most frequent hours and break for that day.

Comment: Not yet downvoting - but are you serious? 3 Subselects for a query determining "sum and average" for a single user?

Comment: It works, however, I should get better at explaining. I used the example in the original post as it's a lot shorter than in my actual project, I have a lot more columns, therefore it wouldn't be great.

Comment: This won't be that costly since we already came down to one single value for day. If proper index exists on that column, you can see that all of them will run fast. Besides, MySQL doesn't have window functions - so subqueries will be needed as all the selected values are in their own sort order.

Comment: Also i'm trying to update a row in a table with the data from the query

Comment: @James - You can use this to update your table using update-join syntax

Comment: @GurwinderSingh okay, so in my actual project, I have 32 columns and 96 rows. 1 of the rows is empty with the id 0 and the name, "mostfrequent" and is where i'm trying to insert the values into

Comment: @James - Don't look just at the output of my query. First check if I get your logic right. If not, there is no further point in discussion. I'll then have to revise the answer.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yeah, you've got my logic right in what I'm trying to achieve. It's just on a much larger scale

Comment: @James - There is no other way using just SQL as far as I can think at the moment. Perhaps, a little application side manipulation would help. But I think your requirements are bit different and difficult to meet with current table structure. Perhaps consider rethinking the table design

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you mention the column-count right away?

Querying for 3 "most occured" values is either 3 queries, or the solution mentioned bellow. Scaling this to 32 columns - Well, neither subselects nor independent queries seem helpful.

In this case I would definitly use some sort of `foreach` in the language you are using? (PHP?)

So, first: Get all Columns. 
2nd: For each column, count & do the insert:

Example code:

```
$valueArray() = array();
$dbConnection->Query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable");
while ($row = $dbConnection->getResultRow()){
   $column = $row["Field"]; //Static field name when using SHOW COLUMNS

   $actualQuery = "SELECT $column, count(*) as ct FROM mytable GROUP BY $column ORDER BY count(*) LIMIT 0,1";
   $dbConnection2->Query($actualQuery);
   $subRow = $dbConnection2->getResultRow();

   //now delivers the count value per $Field.
   $valueArray[$column] = array("key" => $subRow[$column], "value" => $subRow["ct"];
}

//finally - assuming fields "day, hours, break"
array(
  "day" => ( key => "Monday", value => 2),
  "hours" => (key => "8", value => 2),
  "break" => (key => "1", value => 2)
)
```

(untested, but something like this should work out)